# how function(global){...}(this) works?

Tags: javascript, module

[AirBnb Javascript Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/es5#modules) recommends the following code pattern for modules:

```
// fancyInput/fancyInput.js

!function(global) {
    'use strict';

    var previousFancyInput = global.FancyInput;

    function FancyInput(options) {
        this.options = options || {};
    }

    FancyInput.noConflict = function noConflict() {
        global.FancyInput = previousFancyInput;
        return FancyInput;
    };

    global.FancyInput = FancyInput;
}(this);
```

But once you run for example:

```
FancyInput({a: 1, b: 2});
```

The console show this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'options' of undefined".

I'm trying to understand why this inside FancyInput function is Window. So far I have could extend this module patter because the very begining. Should I bind it in another way?

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling that with `var x = new FancyInput({...})`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gist of it is that `this` in the global scope, in a browser, is `window`.  In other environments (mainly node.js), it's not `window`, but rather a different global object, but in many ways we care about it acts the same.

Your code isn't working because you need to instantiate the structure using the `new` keyword:

```
new FancyInput({a: 1, b: 2});
```

which creates a new object so that `this.` works within the class methods & constructor.